# Загрузка JS кода через AJAX, но не через innerHTML

Tags: ajax, javascript

Приветствую всех, уважаемые форумчане. У меня парочка вопросов к профи JS (ajax).
Насколько мне известно, подключенный код вида `<script src="/js.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` вставленный в DOM через innerHTML работает не во всех браузерах надлежащим образом, и поэтому нужен альтернативный способ подключить JS.

У меня одна мысль! Весь сайт работает на ajax (c history API, разумеется). Приемлемо для нормального веб-проекта распарсить все данные, полученные через AJAX, выдернуть все теги `<script>` и подключить найденный JS код через `createElement`? Или есть другой более разумный способ?

Второй вопрос. Т.к. сайт работает на AJAX, отработавший JS код остается в памяти (если, к примеру, пользователь из чата перешел в галерею, то код чата так и остался в памяти, хотя он уже не нужен). Нормально ли просто тупо сбрасывать объект подобным образом: `chat = {}`? Или же опять имеется какой-то другой более разумный способ?

Кстати, объект из памяти сразу очищается, если его обнулить вот так: `chat = {}`? Или же сборщик мусора потом с ним разберется?

Answer (score 1):

- Вынесите все скрипты из страниц в js-файлы и подключайте их
  нормально.
- Я в таких случаях делаю просто chat = null и не парюсь. Проблем не
  возникало.